# Como enviar parametros por medio de ruta?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy tratando de enviar un parámetro `string` desde una búsqueda en Android, pero no he tenido éxito para que lo lea Laravel, he estado viendo tutoriales y resulta que con un `dd` en la función Laravel puedo imprimir el valor que estoy pasando pero no genera tal resultado, creé esta función:

```
 Public function getBusqueda(Request $request)
    {
      dd($request->get('term'));


       $posts = Post::with("author", "category", "tags", "coautore" )
                     ->latestFirst()
                     ->published();

        return response()->json($posts);
    }
```

con esta ruta:

> Route::get("posts/{term}", "Api\ApipostController@getBusqueda");

y sigo obteniendo json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y según el tutorial debería de aparecer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor, que alguien me diga qué hago mal y cómo corregirlo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: pero en que parte de la consulta estas delimitando que solo te muestre un valor del JSON completo?

Comment: prueba modificar los parametros de tu funcion `(Request $request)` por `(Request $request, $term)` y luego usas esa variable.

Answer (score 0):

ya logres pasar el parametro, aun cuando hice la prueba si el scope lo recibia bien y todo bien pero igual no hace la busqueda solo queda en {}.

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $term)
{

    dd("scope:" . $term);

       if ($term)
  {
    $query->where(function($q) use ($term) {
       $q->whereHas('author', function($qr) use ($term) {
       $qr->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%");
       });
       $q->orWhereHas('coautore', function($qr) use ($term) {
       $qr->where('name', 'LIKE',  "%{$term}%");
       });
       $q->orWhereHas('tags', function($qr) use ($term) {
       $qr->where('name', 'LIKE',  "%{$term}%");
       });
         $q->orWhereHas('category', function($qr) use ($term) {
         $qr->where('title', 'LIKE',  "%{$term}%");
       });
        $q->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%");
        $q->orWhere('excerpt', 'LIKE',  "%{$term}%");
        $q->orWhere('body', 'LIKE',  "%{$term}%");
       });
  }
  return $query;

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿cuál fue la solución a la pregunta planteada?

Comment: la solución fue hacia falta ->get(), al final de la función